# i want to add an action to the windows key in debian , so as to open up gnome terminal .how to do so?

Tags: linux

how to open a gnome terminal by pressing the windows key in debian ?

Comment: how is this programming related?

Comment: well ,dont i have to use shell scripting ?

Comment: Nope, it's configured. Somehow.

Comment: what do you mean by somehow?

Comment: If I knew I'd tell you. I'm a developer, not a system administrator. That's why people are voting to move your question to superuser.com .

Comment: Here, I'll upvote your question to try and get you some more attention. But it's sleepy time in much of the USA.

Comment: ah thanks .. I just read few articles on it , as to how to add actions to various keys , but it involves a lot of shell scripting and binding , which i thought someone could explain me here

Answer (score 1):

It so happens I'm running Ubuntu, which is a Debian derivative.

```
System | Preferences | Keyboard shortcuts
```

at least on my system already has a (disabled) entry for starting up a terminal. All you have to do is set a key to do this for you.

The Windows key is a bit strange, I'm not sure you can map it successfully but it's worth a try.